# mongoose.updateOne() always updating the first document

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm making a command for a discord bot in which I want to edit user's info in document. The command looks like this `!edit @tag email language` this works however it doesnt matter who I ping it will always change the first document in MongoDB.

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first()

Data.findOne({
     userID: user.id,
}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    if (!data) {
         return message.reply("That user isn't in list")
    } else {
         Data.updateOne({
             language: args[2],
             email: args[1]
         }, (err) => {
             if (err) throw err;
             let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .addField("Name", data.name);
                message.channel.send(embed)
            })
        }
```

Data.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    language: String,
    email: String,
    userID: String,
    lb: String,
    usage: Number
})

module.exports = mongoose.model(`Data`, dataSchema)
```

This is how my documents look like

[image: This is how my documents look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you should try this

```js
Data.findOneAndUpdate({ userID: user.id },
  { $set: { language: args[2], email: args[1] } },
  { new: true }).exec((err, data) => {
     //further response with updated data
});
```

Comment: Fixed the code because you mistype in it but it works! I get this warning though `Mongoose: 'findOneAndUpdate()' and 'findOneAndDelete()' without the 'useFindAndModify' option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify`